# ¿porque no devuelve todas las filas en el gridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Probando este método que cuando en un gridview con checkbox si se selecciona 1 checkbox pues sale un modal con esa seleccion en otro gridview, y si se seleccionan 2 o mas checkbox en el primer gridview se muestran las filas seleccionadas en otro gridview. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero ahora necesito convertir cada una de las filas del gridview en xml para pasarlo a un webservice, esa es la idea principal, pero el label no me muestra mas de 1 fila, no me muestra 2 o 3 o más filas.

Código:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gwPreview.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                    string ciudad = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblCONSULTA") as Label).Text;
                    string data = row.Cells[2].Text;
                    string remision = row.Cells[3].Text;
                    string fechaEmision = row.Cells[4].Text;
                    dt.Rows.Add(ciudad, data, remision, fechaEmision);

                    lblHelper1.Text = "<code>" + " | " + ciudad + " | " + data + " | " + remision + " | " + fechaEmision + "</code>" 
                }
            }
        }
        gvSelected.DataSource = dt;
        gvSelected.DataBind();
```

Gridview1

```
ciudad | data | remision | fechaemision | checkbox 
----------------------------------------|---------
city1  |  01  |    2448  | 20171010     |   X 
city2  |  02  |    2447  | 20171021     |   X
city3  |  03  |    2457  | 20170928     |
```

GridviewPreview

```
ciudad | data | remision | fechaemision | 
----------------------------------------|
city1  |  01  |    2448  | 20171010     | 
city2  |  02  |    2447  | 20171021     |
```

lblHelper1 obtenido

```
city1  | 01 | 2448 | 20171010
```

lblHelper1 resultado Esperado

```
city1  | 01 | 2448 | 20171010 | city2 | 02 | 2447 | 20171021
```

Comment: Cuando asignas `lblHelper1.Text = ...` no estás reemplazando lo que ya hay escrito? Aunque en tal caso, debería mostrarse `city2` únicamente.

Comment: Coges el checkbox de la primera columna: CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox); pero no está en la última???

Comment: Flowen, no comprendo compa. Pablo, pues para eso creo que es el foreach no? porque todos las filas que se seleccionana si se muestran en el otro gridview, pero no en el label como cadena de texto.

Comment: @Vulpex prueba de poner  `lblHelper1.Text += ...`

Comment: @Marc Eso era lo que quería decir. Pero si el error fuera ese, ahora debería estar mostrándose `city2` en vez de `city1`

Comment: @Flowen Si, lo he visto, pero tampoco me concuerdan los resultados que muestra Vulpex, ya que `"<code>" + " | " + ciudad + " | " + data + " | " + remision + " | " + fechaEmision + "</code>"` da como resultado `| city1  | 01 | 2448 | 20171010`

Comment: @Marc, Eso era!!! eres un genio compa, pero.. podrías decirme porque con el += funciona? (ponla como respuesta para marcarla compa) :)

Comment: @Vulpex Como te he dicho al principio, cada vez que lanzas `lblHelper1.Text =...` estás sustituyendo el texto que ya está por el nuevo. Por lo que siempre va a mostrarse sólo la última fila insertada.

Comment: Ahhhh!!! ya entendí, muchas gracias por la explicación, @Marc, Flowen

Comment: Si que haces el foreach pero para recorrer las filas, dentro de las columnas le indicas que coja la columna 0, con lo cual estás comprobando todas las filas y dentro de ellas la primera celda, sinceramente, no se como te funciona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás reescribiendo el contenido del `label` cada vez que le asignas un valor con el `lblHelper1.Text = ...`.

Para poder añadir valor después del texto que ya contiene el label se usa la expresión `+=`:

```
lblHelper1.Text += ...
```

Que viene siendo lo mismo que hacer:

```
lblHelper1.Text = lblHelper1.Text + ...
```